# Is it possible to directly apply for residence permit in Germany as non-EU holder of residence permit of another EU country?

Tags: germany, working-visas, residency, greencard

I am from a non-EU country and currently stay in Germany at my family. From Portugal, I have a residence permit for the purpose of study according to §91 of Portugal Aliens Act. Recently I have received a formal job offer in Germany. I already have my course certificate, Meldebescheinigung (proof of residence) and made an online appointement at Landratsamt München in oder to try to apply for a residence permit in Germany, however it will only happen 3 months from today.

What should I do? My contract could be cancelled if I am unable to work for these next months to come since I will be of no use.

Is it implied that I have temporary permission to practice my profession or should I wait for the full completion of the process to start working?

Comment: The question is unclear, what is exactly written on your visa (student and looking for a job are two different purposes of stay)? Where did you went to make online appointment (why do you need to go somewhere for online appointment at all?? Landkreis translates into something like region or county or district, so it is not clear at all where did you get an appointment).
You might have a permission for work depending on what is written on your visa.

Comment: Sorry, I have assumed too much to cut to the chase, student visas do not allow working. I went on the website of the District office, in which is responsible for expedition of working visas (however, due to the pandemic it is an online appointment). My question still begs the same, is it not countraintuitive to appoint an interview for a job visa 3 months for now, in which the offer itself won't hold up that long?

Comment: student visa may allow working. at least student residence permit do. My questions still remain unanswered. It is unclear, what is "District office", and you haven't provided any info about what is written on your visa (purpose of stay, based on which § of law was it issued and so on).

Comment: I beg your pardon, answering what is the District Office I will put the link of the site itself in hopes it can elucidate the misunderstanding: https://www.landkreis-muenchen.de/.
About the student visa I am aware that in some cases it is possible to work, however my visa was expedited in Portugal (§ art. 91) and on its back is written "Does not allow the exercise of a professional activity". For a student to work it would require a contract and the work hours could not exceed 5h/day, so my plan was only to find a full time job after finishing my studies and make my "greencard". (§ ART.º 89º)

Comment: Can you please provide even more details on your visa? Do you have visa from Portugal, and not Germany? Is it a visa (and you are a tourist in Germany) or residence permit (and you have exchange semester in Germany)?

Comment: Yes, it is from Portugal, in its card it reads "Residence Card", however I am not sure how it applies to Germany. I came here to visit my family, which legally resides here, but the situation has changed so much in Portugal that I decided to look for a job here.

Comment: Just an adendo, I received this morning this confusing answer from the responsibles for my work permit:

"After consultation with my colleague, I can inform you that you must first apply for a visa to take up employment. You can apply for a visa at the German Embassy in Lisbon.

Without a visa, it is not possible to grant you a residence permit for gainful employment.

Without a visa, you can stay in Germany as a tourist for 90 days."

Meaning I should schedulle a meeting in the german embassy in Portugal, so I can come here to find a job?

Comment: Yes, this could be the case. There are some exceptions, of course, like if one is a student in Portugal and an exchange student in Germany, one can stay with a single residence permit. But in general case, I would expect that you are in the tourist status now. To apply for a national visa (to later get a residence permit), one needs to go to the German embassy in the country where one has a residence (Portugal in this case). The employment contract one can probably still sign, but on the first working day one needs to have a corresponding visa and work permit. P.S. I'm not a lawyer.

Comment: @TomasBy: great links, however, it depends on the country of origin if direct application for residence and work permit is possible, or first visa should be applied for at the embassy (see your first link). So if OP is not an exchange student, and not from EU or USA, Canada, Australia, New Zealand, Israel, Japan, or South Korea, with high probability he won't be able to apply for residence permit from inside Germany, where he is just a tourist.

Comment: Thank you all for your consideration, it really helped me to empty all the possibilities. Unfortunatelly, the employer is not willing to hire me under these circunstances and I am leaving the country. However, I am glad for all your help and attention to help a complete stranger, godspeed to you all.

Comment: You do not need to inform your employer about this. Just find a job which starts 1-3 months later, sign a contract and appy for a German visa in the Portugal.

Comment: I did tried looking at it in the morning, however the embassies are not working or taking meetings. Meaning its not possible to apply to a German Visa during the pandemic.

Comment: You need to apply for German national visa, not Schengen / tourist visa. I'm pretty sure it is possible.

Comment: I will keep trying. Thank you Andrey for your HUGE help and support.